# Does math.dist take a list, or an integer?

Tags: python, list, math, distance

I am making some code that looks like this:

```
import math

def get_coord_distance():
    c_1 = input('What is the coordinate of the first point?\n').split(',')
    c_2 = input('What is the coordinate of the second point?\n').split(',')
    
    p = []
    q = []
    p.append(c_1)
    q.append(c_2)

    coordinate_distance = math.dist(p, q)
    if p == q:
        print('The two points equal each other. The distance is 0.')
        exit()
    return coordinate_distance

res = get_coord_distance()
print(res)
```

math.dist uses two lists, and uses the distance formula and outputs the distance between the two lists. This looks like:

```
p = [3, 14]
q = [1, 59]

print(math.dist(p, q))
```

This would output a floatpoint number like this:

```
45.04442251822083
```

When I run the code above (The first code block), I get an error message.

```
TypeError: must be real number, not list
```

What is my mistake here? I think this is a bug with the math module, but I'm not sure.

Comment: `c_1` is a list itself. When you append it to an empty list, `p` becomes a list of lists of strings, e.g. `[["3", "14"]]`.

Comment: "I think this is a bug with the math module" -- why think that? The chance that there is a bug in a heavily used python module is much, much smaller than the chance that there is a bug in your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You got 2 things wrong. First you need to convert your inputs. Second you shouldn't append to p & q but extend. Try the below code

Please note instead of extending an empty list. I have used `map` function to get converted coordinates and assigned to P & Q directly

```
import math


def get_coord_distance():
    c_1 = input('What is the coordinate of the first point?\n').split(',')
    c_2 = input('What is the coordinate of the second point?\n').split(',')

    p = map(int, c_1)
    q = map(int, c_2)

    coordinate_distance = math.dist(p, q)
    if p == q:
        print('The two points equal each other. The distance is 0.')
        exit()
    return coordinate_distance


res = get_coord_distance()
print(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

For those like me who get this error:

> AttributeError: module 'math' has no attribute 'dist'

you can calculate distance between two points like this too:

```
import math

def get_coord_distance():
    a=input("What is the coordinate of the first point : ")

    p1 = a.split(",")

    b=input("What is the coordinate of the second point : ")

    p2 = b.split(",")

    coordinate_distance = math.sqrt( ((int(p1[0])-int(p2[0]))**2)+((int(p1[1])-int(p2[1]))**2) )

    return coordinate_distance


res = get_coord_distance()
print(res)
```